# Page only shows half of the absolute positioned popup

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a page that has some functionality that triggers a popup. That popup is defined as a div with some contents. That div has some css to give it a proper look, and also contains `position:absolute`.

The overlay is positioned relative to another element (the one that trigger it on the page and that element might be anywhere as the page is created dynamically), and sets the top of the popup equals to the bottom of the trigger element.

The popup is shown correctly most of the time, but if the trigger element is a the bottom part of the page, only the top part of the popup is visible. And for some reason (maybe because it's a absolute positioned element?) I don't get the posibility to scroll in the browser so I can see the rest of the contents.

Are there any way I can make it so that the popup "counts" as part of the page, and therefore enables scrolling inside the browser to be able to see all the contents?

Comment: Consider positioning the popup dynamically, instead of scrolling the page for it to display: If there is no more space on the bottom, show it on top (-offSet instead of +offSet), vice versa for the right window border.

Answer (score -1):

Try `.appendTo('body');` at the end of the calling line for the popup.

Another possibility to resolve the scrolling issue would be to use `position:fixed;` instead of `position:absolute;`

Comment: Adding position:fixed would not have the same behavior as described in the question.